# kendo UI for jquery grid's active page change by code

Tags: jquery, user-interface, pagination, kendo-ui, grid

I'd like to know, is there any approach to programmatically change grid's active page after calling dataSource.read transport method?

If I use dataSource.page(x), I'm having an infinite call chain, cos of cyclic transport's read() call.

I dont want to call dataSource read, my data is okay. I'd like to change grid's visual pager only, like "page 7 of 100".

Thank you.

Any *.page(x) method call, datasource's or pager's, causing dataSource read transport, which is not necessary.

```
const fRead = function (e) {
    //consider this call is REST to somewhere
    const res = {
        data: [{
                m: 1
            }, {
                m: 2
            }, {
                m: 3
            }, {
                m: 4
            }, {
                m: 5
            }, {
                m: 6
            }
        ],
        page: 2
    };
    return e.success(res);
    //after fRead I want the grid's active page set to page 2!
}

const newKnd = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {m: {type:"number"}}
        }
    }
    pageSize: 6,
    pageable: true,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    sort: _sort,
    transport: {
        read: fRead,
    },
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Calling page() is the correct way to change it. How are your grid and datasource defined? What options do you have set on them, for example serverPaging?

Comment: I want the pager settings to be managed by REST data, not the data managed by the pager. Here is an example.